Derivation of torsion formula - do Carmo exercise 1.5.12
The problem: Let $\alpha \colon I \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular parametrized curve
(not necessarily arc length) and let $\beta \colon
J \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a reparametrization of $\alpha(I)$ by
the arc length $s = s(t)$, measured from $t_0 \in I$. Let
$t \colon J = s(I) \to I$ be the inverse of $s$.\
The curvature of $\alpha$ is
$$
k = \frac{\left| \alpha' \wedge \alpha'' \right| }{\left| 
\alpha' \right|^3 }
$$
Show that the torsion of $\alpha$ is
$$
\tau = - \frac{\left( \alpha' \wedge \alpha'' \right) \cdot 
\alpha'''}{\left| \alpha' \wedge \alpha'' \right|^2}.
$$

I've done the following, but I get the answer from the book with the constant $\left|\alpha' \right|$ multiplied onto it:

We are given that
$$
t' = \frac{1}{\left|\alpha' \right|} \quad \text{and} \quad
t'' = - \frac{\alpha' \cdot \alpha''}{\left| \alpha' \right|^4}.
$$
So we have
$$
\beta'' = \left( \alpha \circ t \right)'' = \alpha'' (t')^2 + \alpha' t'' 
= \frac{\alpha''}{\left| a' \right|^2} -
\frac{\alpha' \left<\alpha', \alpha'' \right>}{\left| \alpha' \right|^{4}}= kn
= \frac{\left| \alpha' \wedge \alpha'' \right| }{\left| \alpha' \right|^3}n
$$
hence
$$
n = \frac{\left| \alpha' \right| }{\left| \alpha' \wedge \alpha'' \right| } 
 \alpha'' - \frac{\left<\alpha', \alpha'' \right>}{\left| a' \right| } \alpha'.
$$
Now the binormal vector $b$ is
$$
 b = \frac{\alpha'}{\left| \alpha' \right| } \wedge n
 = \frac{\alpha'}{\left| \alpha' \right| } \wedge
 \frac{\left| \alpha' \right| }{\left| \alpha' \wedge \alpha'' \right|
 } \alpha'' =
 \frac{\alpha' \wedge \alpha''}{\left| \alpha' \wedge \alpha'' \right| }
$$
Hence
$$
b' = \frac{\alpha' \wedge \alpha'''}{\left| \alpha' \wedge \alpha'' \right|} - \frac{\alpha' \wedge \alpha''}{\left| \alpha' \wedge \alpha'' \right|^2}
\frac{d}{dt} \left| \alpha' \wedge \alpha'' \right|.
$$
We know that $b' = \tau n$, so since  $\left| n \right| =1$, we have
$\tau = b' \cdot n$ and this is
$$
 \tau = \frac{\left| \alpha' \right| }{\left| \alpha' \wedge \alpha'' \right|^2}
 \left( \alpha' \wedge \alpha''' \right) \cdot \alpha''
 = \left| \alpha' \right| \frac{- \left( \alpha' \wedge \alpha'' \right) \cdot 
 \alpha'''}{\left| \alpha' \wedge \alpha'' \right|^2}
$$

You have forgotten the meaning of $'$. It is, of course, differentiation with respect to $t$, but when you get to $b'=\tau n$, of course, it denotes differentiation with respect to $s$. You need the chain rule correction factor.

Ah, that makes sense. Now that I think about it, in the above, the left hand sides are in reality all composed with $s$ by an abuse of notation, right? So for example, in the formula for $n$, the right hand side is really $n \circ s$, and likewise for $b$. This then gives the correct differentiation of $b$ with respect to $s$.
And then the final formula really reads: $\tau \circ s = - \frac{(\alpha' \wedge \alpha'') \cdot \alpha'''}{\left| \alpha' \wedge \alpha'' \right|^2}$, right?

Right. In such calculations, I’ve found that the Leibniz notation for derivatives yields better bookkeeping. You might want to check out my diff geo text, linked (free) in my profile.

Reparametrize by arclenght $\alpha(t)=\beta(s(t))$. By the chain rule we get:
$$
\alpha'(t)=\beta'(s(t))s'(t) = \mathbf{t}(s(t))s'(t).
$$
From now on denote $\nu(t)=s'(t)$ (which is actually the speed). Also note that using Frenet formulas we get
$$
\mathbf{t}(s(t))' = \mathbf{t}'(s(t))\nu(t) = \nu(t)\cdot\kappa(s(t))\cdot \mathbf{n}(s(t)).
$$
(where $'$ denotes derivative with respect to $t$). Thus we can compute the following derivates using Frenet formulas:
\begin{align}
\alpha' &= \nu \mathbf{t}, \\
\alpha'' &= \nu'\mathbf{t} + \nu \mathbf{t}' \\
&=  \nu'\mathbf{t} + \kappa\nu^2\mathbf{n},\\
\alpha''' &= \nu''\mathbf{t} + \kappa\nu\nu'\textbf{n} + (\kappa\nu^2)'\mathbf{n} + \kappa\nu^2\mathbf{n}'\nu\\
&= \nu''\mathbf{t} + \kappa\nu\nu'\textbf{n} + (\kappa\nu^2)'\mathbf{n} + \kappa\nu^3(-\kappa\mathbf{t} + \tau\mathbf{b})\\
&= (\nu'' - \kappa^2\nu^3)\mathbf{t} + (\kappa\nu\nu'+(\kappa\nu^2)')\mathbf{n} + \kappa\tau\nu^3\mathbf{b}.
\end{align}
From the previous computations it can be verified that $||\alpha'\times \alpha''|| = \kappa\nu^3$. This gives the formula for $\kappa$.
Now, using the properties of the cross product $\times$ (denoted above as $\wedge$) we compute:
\begin{align}
\alpha'' \times \alpha''' 
&= (\cdots) \mathbf{t} \times \mathbf{n} + (\cdots) \mathbf{t}\times\mathbf{b} + (\cdots)\textbf{n}\times\textbf{t} + \kappa\nu^2(\kappa\tau\nu^3)\textbf{n}\times\textbf{b}\\
&= (\kappa^2\nu^5\tau)\textbf{t} + (\cdots)\textbf{n} + (\cdots)\textbf{b}. 
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
\alpha'\cdot (\alpha'' \times \alpha''') = \tau\kappa^2\nu^6 = \tau|| \alpha' \times \alpha'' ||^2.
\end{align}
Finally,
\begin{align}
\tau = \frac{\alpha'\cdot (\alpha'' \times \alpha''')}{|| \alpha' \times \alpha'' ||^2}.
\end{align}
As mentioned in the comments, I would also recommend taking a look at the Differential Geometry (free) book by Dr. Shifrin.
